# User and host names in the public key on ssh-copy-id

Tags: ssh, users, key-authentication

Username and hostname is automatically appended to the server-side `authorized_keys` files on `ssh-copy-id` execution so the public key contain `user@host` revailing information.

I removed them manually form the file on the server side, and could reconnect passwordless successfully.

Is it possible to change `sshd-id` behaviour to not to append that last part in the file which seems to be optional and not required ?

To add, I've generated keys by `ssh-keygen` which defaulted to the `rsa` type, and made no encrpytion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in [ssh-keygen man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) :

The *user@host* is a default comment added by `ssh-keygen`:

> For RSA1 keys, there is also a comment field in the key file that is
>   only for convenience to the user to help identify the key. The comment
>   can tell what the key is for, or whatever is useful. The comment is
>   initialized to ''user@host'' when the key is created, but can be
>   changed using the -c option.

You can use the -C / -c options to set a different comment

> -C comment Provides a new comment.
>
> -c' Requests changing the comment in the private and public key files. This operation is only supported for RSA1 keys. The program will
>   prompt for the file containing the private keys, for the passphrase if
>   the key has one, and for the new comment.

e.g. using the flag `-C ""` as follows will set *empty comment* in the public key

```
ssh-keygen -C ""
```

Comment: Thanks. To note, there's no comment field in the **private key** file of the default RSA type; and the `-C string` adds the input comment *only to the public key*.

Comment: I would recommend using _some_ kind of comment. You're going to be pasting this public key into `authorized_keys` files (or into github or whatever), and you'll want to know which key to revoke when your laptop gets stolen (for example).